# Sorting output content by file input

Tags: shell-script, filenames, sort

What the code does is that it prints depending on the line from a file the word that comes up the most.
This is the code :

```
for i in $@;
do
    readlink -f $i
    while read line; do
        echo $line | sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+/\n/g' | sed '/^$/d'|sort | uniq -c| sort -g| tail -1
    done < $i 
done
```

I need to sort what is shown depending on the file it comes from; if it comes from file `a.txt` it should be first, if it comes from `x.txt` it should be last (alphabetically).

Comment: Welcome on U&L! I removed some tags ([tag:awk], [tag:echo], [tag:read], [tag:for]) because tags should describe what the question is _about_, e.g. what you are having issues with, not the things that the question _contains_. Please feel free to add the relevant ones back if e.g. you need a solution that makes use of a specific tool.

Comment: Please give us a couple of sample files, and your desired output.